# Actionscript ByteArray (from NFC) to String

Tags: actionscript, air, arrays

I'm reading an NFC tag in my Adobe AIR mobile app. The data is read as a ByteArray, but I'm having difficulty pulling the full text. The sample text on the tag is "http://www.google.com"

Using this method, I get a portion of the String "http://www.goog", but not all of it. I'm assuming because each character is not a single byte:

```
private static function convertToString(byte_array : ByteArray) : String {
        var arr : Array = [];
        for (var i : Number = 1 ; i <= byte_array.bytesAvailable; i++) {
            arr.push(byte_array.readUTFBytes(i));
        }

        var finalString : String = "";
        for (var t : Number = 0; t < arr.length;t++) {
            finalString = finalString + arr[t].toString();
        }

        return finalString;
    }
```

I've also tried the method below, but it returns null:

```
bytes.readUTF();
```

I'm wondering if I need to convert the byteArray to a base64 string and then decode that. It seems like an extra step, but that's how I've done it before when sending data to/from a server using AMFPHP.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even simplify this code by simply calling

```
private static function convertToString(bytes:ByteArray):String {
    bytes.position = 0;
    var str:String = bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length);

    return str;
}
```

This way you will read all contents of the bytearray in one single method call into your destination string.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the code below. 
There were 2 errors, plus some cleanup:

```
    private static function convertToString(bytes : ByteArray) : String {
        bytes.position = 0;
        var str : String = '';
        while (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) {
            str += bytes.readUTFBytes(1);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

- the "bytesAvailable" property decreases as you read from the ByteArray. Here, I'm checking if the bytes > 0 instead of the length
- the "readUTFBytes" method takes a length parameter (not position). Position is automatically updated as you read from the ByteArray. I'm passing in "1" instead of "i"